# Showing a sequence decreases and its bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

So far I have proven that the sequences decreases and used the definition of a inf to show its bounded below. How do I find its limit. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of proof:

1. Using induction, show that $1\leq a_j\leq 2$
2. Show that $a_{j+1}-a_j \leq 0$, so the sequence is decreasing.
3. Since it has a lower bound and is decreasing, it has a limit.
4. Take limits on both sides, you will get $x=x-\frac{x^2-2}{2x}$. Solve this, you can get the limit $\sqrt{2}$.